# How to get ProcessDefinition using jpdl for JBPM 4.4?

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm, jpdl

In my project there is an existing old.jpdl.xml definition. It is working fine.
Now I want to run another new.jpdl.xml definition.
After deployment of ear file I tried to read new.jpdl.xml using new ProcessDefinitionId with help of below code.

I believe that I am missing deployment steps. Can someone guide me, how to deploy or read new.jpdl.xml?

```
public String getProcessInstanceID(ProcessEngine processEngine,
            FlowControl flowcontrol, String processDefinitionID)
    {
        String processInstanceID = null;
        log.debug("Entering method - getProcessInstanceID");
        ProcessDefinitionQuery pdq = processEngine.getRepositoryService()
                .createProcessDefinitionQuery();
        pdq.deploymentId(processDefinitionID);
        ProcessDefinition procDef = pdq.uniqueResult();

        if (null == procDef)
        {
            log.error("Process Definition could not be found for the deployment ID: "
                    + processDefinitionID);
        }

        Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        variables.put("flowcontrol", flowcontrol);

        ProcessInstance processInstance = processEngine.getExecutionService()
                .startProcessInstanceByKey(procDef.getKey(), variables);

        log.debug("Process Instance ID:" + processInstance.getId());
        processInstanceID = processInstance.getId();
        log.debug("Exiting method - getProcessInstanceID");
        return processInstanceID;
    }
```

Comment: It seems like your question isn't getting a lot of views here. You might want to try asking in the [Official JBPM forum](https://developer.jboss.org/en/jbpm/content).

Comment: Hi Mike, I got the solution of this problem. Thanks for helping me. I will use this forum for other queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a batch job to deploy jpdl file. JBPM api internally inserts the values into JBPM4_XXX tables after successful deployment. Below class I have used to deploy the new jpdl file. For passing values of jpdl name and key, I have used spring dependency.
Finally these steps worked successfully.

```
    public class JBPMDeploymentService extends BatchService {

            /**
             *  Logger for Batch service
             */
            protected static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NAPSJBPMDeploymentService.class);

            private Map<String, String> jpdlMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            private Map<String, String> procInstMap = new HashMap<String, String> ();

            public void doService() throws NAPSBatchException
            {
                log.info("Entering into doService Method of JBPMDeploymentService ...");
                String approvalFlow = getJpdlFileType();

                String jpdlXML = getJPDLxml(approvalFlow);

                String procInst = getProcessInstanceKey(approvalFlow);

                // constructs the ProcessEngine
                ProcessEngine processEngine = new Configuration().setResource("naps.jbpm.cfg.xml").buildProcessEngine();

                // retrieve the needed services
                RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
                ExecutionService executionService = processEngine.getExecutionService();



                repositoryService.createDeployment()
                .addResourceFromClasspath(jpdlXML)
                .deploy();
                //executionService.startProcessInstanceByKey(procInst);

            }

    /**
         * @return the jpdlMap
         */
        public Map<String, String> getJpdlMap() {
            return jpdlMap;
        }

        /**
         * @param jpdlMap the jpdlMap to set
         */
        public void setJpdlMap(Map<String, String> jpdlMap) {
            this.jpdlMap = jpdlMap;
        }

        /**
         * @param jpdlKey
         * @return jpdl xml name
         */
        private String getJPDLxml(String jpdlKey)
        {
            return jpdlMap.get(jpdlKey);
        }

        /**
         * @return the procInstMap
         */
        public Map<String, String> getProcInstMap() {
            return procInstMap;
        }

        /**
         * @param procInstMap the procInstMap to set
         */
        public void setProcInstMap(Map<String, String> procInstMap) {
            this.procInstMap = procInstMap;
        }

        /**
         * @param procInstKey
         * @return process Instance key
         */
        private String getProcessInstanceKey(String procInstKey){
            return this.procInstMap.get(procInstKey);
        }
}
```